# jQuery validate not working with jQuery multiselect

Tags: c#, jquery-validate

I am using the jQuery validator to validate a jQuery multiselect dropdownlist but it does not validate, my functions are bellow:

These functions are created from my code behind and registered on the page with the  ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock.

I put the following directly on the aspx page and it then validates the multiselect, but as soon as I do it from the code behind and register the script, all validators besides the multiselect works.

```
$.validator.addMethod('notNone', function(value, element) {  
            return (value != '-1');
        }, 'Please select an option.');

var $callback = $("#callback");
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#<%=example.ClientID%>").multiselect(
            {
                show: "fade",
                hide: "fade",
                click: function (event, ui) {
                    $callback.text(ui.text + ' ' + (ui.checked ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'));
                },
            });
        });

 $("#form1").validate({
                rules: {
                    <%=example.UniqueID %>: {
                    notNone: true,
                    },
                    <%=txtPassword.UniqueID %>: {
                        //minlength: 5,
                        //required: true
                    },

                   <%=TextIdea.UniqueID %>: {
                        //minlength: 5,
                        //required: true
                 },

                 <%=ddlTest.UniqueID %>: {
                        //notNone: true
                 },

                 redemption : {
                        redemption : false
                 },

                 redemption: {
                        redemptionEnd : false
                        },
                 },
ignore: ':hidden:not("#<%=example.ClientID %>")',

                 messages: {
                    <%=example.UniqueID %>:{
                        notNone: "Plaese select something",                            
                        },
                    <%=txtPassword.UniqueID %>:{
                        required: "Plaese enter your password",
                        minlength: "Password must be atleaet of 5 characters"
                         },    
                     <%=TextIdea.UniqueID %>:{
                      required: "Plaese enter your Ideas",
                      minlength: "Password must be atleaet of 5 characters"
                },
              }
            });
```

My markup:

```
<select id="example" name="example" runat="server">
    </select>
```

Am I doing something wrong? Please help guys.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which multiselect plugin are you using (there are few out there) - we need to know in order to see how it stores it values.

Comment: I am using the one from :
http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after 2 days I finally figured out what was going on, turns out the controls that use the jQuery multiSelect, their UniqueID gets appended with _multiSelect and the ClientID gets appended with $multiSelect.

Added those strings when getting the Client/UniqueID and it works.